# #1072 - Key column 'course_name' doesn't exist in table

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I have a table named COURSES . In it I have two columns namely (course_id,course_name). When I tried to drop the column (course_name) SQL produces an error message saying the columns does not exist. However it can be seen clearly that it is present in the table.

CODE:

1. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzeel.png) ALTER TABLE COURSES
   DROP CONSTRAINT course_name;
2. I have tried to drop it via the button provided alongside in sql i.e DROP (shown in red color)

Comment: Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE COURSES;` output. PS. Column <> constraint. PPS. If you need to drop the column which is included into PK then you must drop PRIMARY KEY then drop the column.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.